# Put several divs side by side with a width of 100%

Tags: html, css, layout

I try to get a various number of divs side by side.

This number is will be dynamic.

But in total these `divs` should have the width of exactly 100% (not under, not over).
Is this possible and if so, how can I achieve this?

Something Like:

```
 SCREEN SIZE
|<--------------------->|
```

(for 2 boxes:)

```
|-----------|-----------|
|           |           |
|-----------|-----------|
```

or

(for three boxes:)

```
|-------|-------|-------|
|       |       |       |
|-------|-------|-------|
```

Comment: please explain what you have tried before posting, as at present it sounds very much like "Write me some code. thanks"

Comment: Yes. With CSS. No problem. That could be the answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try flex model, works like a charm!

```
 html, body  { height: 100%; width: 100%; }

.eqWrap { display: flex; }

.eq { padding: 10px; }
.eq:nth-of-type(odd) { background: yellow; }
.eq:nth-of-type(even) { background: lightblue; }
.equalHW { flex: 1; }

<div>
  <h1>EQUAL WIDTH COLUMNS</h1>
  <p>Add display:flex to the parent and flex:1 to the boxes</p>
  <div class="equalHWrap eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHW eq">boo <br> boo</div>
    <div class="equalHW eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalHW eq">shoo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/y7L698nq/

Comment: You're welcome! And you see another cool thing here: the divs all have the same height.. magic flex model :-)

Comment: Yes, great! Do you know how to pretend the text in the divs to get over the border? So that it makes an wordwrap, also if there is no space, like there is a long word?

Comment: this would work on most, but not all browsers (firefox, as well as some older versions of explorer can have some difficulty with it)

Comment: @jbutler483: Also the current firefox? or just older versions?

Comment: Or is there a possiblity, to get the div boxes sorted like in a column and not in a row when display is smaller? (e.g. on phone)

Comment: @progNewFag I haven't firefox on my machine to test, but from recollection I remember having issues :(

Comment: @progNewFag with that in mind, you would have to set a 'min width' to do this 'squish effect', and then after change it to a different effect. In all honest, it'd be more hassle than anything.

Comment: @jbutler483: FF knows how to handle "display: flex" from version 22+ on (we have 32 meanwhile!). Even for older versions there is a solution. If any browser might bring more problems it would be IE (as always)

Comment: @progNewFag: yeah, it's possible to change the layout dynamically to column if the screen size gets too small. Check out this great documentation: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 3):

this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbxmL/2/) shows you how you can achieve 3 boxes side by side. I've edited the css to being:

```
   .left {
  float:left; 
  width:50%;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

which works (even after resizing),

and the html was:

```
<div class="left">...B1</div>
<div class="left">...B2</div>
```

See below for it in action:

```css
.left {
  float:left; 
  width:50%;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="left">...B1</div>
    <div class="left">...B2</div>
```